# passing a form data inside a modal into controller button outside the form without javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter Framework and now, i have a modal with a form inside of it. Now in my modal footer, i put the submit form for it. It is already outside of the modal. Now why is it doesn't submit in my controller?. I put a `var_dump` in my controller for it to echo when it was submitted, I am sending it thru without javascript.

Here is my modal with form:

```
<div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Category</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <form id="frm_category" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="Admin_controls/insertCategory">  
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cat_name">Category: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cat_name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cat_desc">Description: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cat_desc">
                </div>
            </form>    
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="submit" form="frm_category">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function insertCategory() {

        $data = array (
            'Category_name' => $this->input->post('cat_name'),
            'Category_desc' => $this->input->post('cat_desc')
        );
        var_dump($data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your `submit button` before `</form>`. other wise you need `javascript` to submit your form

you can use the following code

```
    <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add Category</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                <form id="frm_category" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="Admin_controls/insertCategory">  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cat_name">Category: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cat_name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cat_desc">Description: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cat_desc">
                    </div>
                </form>    
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("frm_category").submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: how would you do same thing in `react` my `submit` is outside the `form` element

Answer (score 1):

- You should change the button type to submit. So it can submit the form.
- Submit button should be inside of form tag
- I have modified your modal code. And I hope it will work

  ×
        Add Category
      
      
        
            
            
              Category: 
              
            
            
              Description: 
              
            
              
        
      
      
        Add
        Close

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a data then you should follow this step:

1. To `POST` or `GET` you should have add that action attribute in side the `<form>` tag.
2. Now For `post` you need to give address of your controller into the `<form action = "<?= base_url('your_controller/your_function') ?>" method="post">`.
3. Now at the controller side:

   ```
   public function your_function(){
       // By using this you can get all posted data at once
       $your_post_data = $this->input->post();
       // By using this you get the post data seperatedly
       $your_post_data = $this->input->post('user_name'); // your form input name

      //Now for sending data to the model for database querys

       $this->load->model ('your_model');
       $data = $this->your_model->your_model_function($your_post_data);
   }
   ```
4. if you don't want to load model every time then you can add the model in to `__construct`

   ```
   public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct ();

       $this->load->model ('your_model');
       // So now on you just need to call the model name in your function.

   }

   public function your_function(){
     // By using this you can get all posted data at once
     $your_post_data = $this->input->post();
       // By using this you get the post data seperatedly
     $your_post_data = $this->input->post('user_name'); // your form input name

    $data = $this->your_model->your_model_function($your_post_data); 

   }
   ```
5. Now Inside the model:( i am giving example for insert)

   ```
   public function your_model_function($your_post_data ){

       $this->db->insert_batch('your_table_name', $your_post_data );

       //If you want to understing of query execuation
       // for thie you need to enable the log from config.php form config folde.
       //Remove comment from log_message after emeble the log message
       //log_message('debug', 'Last Insert query: ' . print_r($this->db->last_query(), TRUE).' Inserted Data: '.print_r($your_post_data, TRUE));

       if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
           return TRUE;
       } else {
           return FALSE;
       }
   }
   ```

For Mode detail regarding querys please visit this [CI documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

Your Code should be:

```
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Category</h4>
      </div>
      <form id="frm_category" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="<?= base_utl('Admin_controls/insertCategory') ?>"> 
          <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cat_name">Category: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cat_name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cat_desc">Description: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cat_desc">
                    </div>                  
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="submit" form="frm_category">Add</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Your controller should be:

```
public function insertCategory() {

    // You should have to validate befor insert

    $this->load->model ('your_model');
    $your_post_data = $this->input->post();
    $insert_status = $this->your_model->your_model_function($your_post_data); 

    if($insert_status == TRUE){
        //return to your view or load the view

        $this->load->view ('your_view_directory');
    } else {
        // Send Error Message
}
```

For Validation Visit this [CI documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html)

Comment: can you check my code? i am getting a submit button outside the form

Comment: You Need to Put that button within the `<form> </form>` tag